# Parsing a concatenating javascript string

Tags: javascript, parsing, variables, concatenation, split

I have a concatenating javascript string that I need to parse and match "&mediaID=334380" wherever it falls in the string. I need to be able to find "&mediaID=" and then write out the numbers that follow the = and have it end on "

This concatenating var will have only once instance of "&mediaID=334380" in it, but it may be in a different part of the string.

```
var vidPlyrVars = "vidPlayerSchool=" + vid_partner + "&vidPlayerWd=" + vid_width +      "&vidPlayerHt=" + vid_height + "&";
vidPlyrVars += "vidURL=" + vid_url + "&imgURL=" + img_url + "&color_button_bkg=0d141a" + "&color_controls_bkg=0d141a" + "&mediaID=334380" + "&share_buttons=on" + "&vip_url=http://somesite.com/all/index.html" + "&";
vidPlyrVars += "vidTitle=" + escape("some title") + "&";
vidPlyrVars += "autoplay=off&autoplay_refresh=always&full_screen=on&ad_prerolls=off&";
vidPlyrVars += "list_type=none&";
```

I just need the numbers after &mediaID= no matter how many numbers there are. I have tried splitting, but it wont work since the &mediaID= may be in a different location in the string.

*Also. What if the mediaID may or may not have a _ before ID such as media_ID and mediaID. Is there a way to match for both in one regex?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you possibly show the, or an example of the, full string you're working with?

Comment: Consider using a regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions is the way to go here.

Try this in your console:

```
"asdasdasdasdasd&mediaID=645654654&asdasdasdasd=asdasdasdasdasd".match(/&mediaID=[0-9]+/)
```

Also, if you want the number separatedly, you can use

```
"asdasdasdasdasd&mediaID=645654654&asdasdasdasd=asdasdasdasdasd".match(/&mediaID=([0-9]+)/)
```

[0-9]+ means any number from 0 to 9, that occurs at least once. And if you wrap it in parentheses, it'll store it in the response (which is an array, by the way).

Let me know if there's any other doubt. Cheers!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much to everyone who responded. Looks like .match with some regular expressions was the way to go. I was fooling around with it, but just couldn't get it. Thanks!

Comment: What if the mediaID may or may not have a _ before ID such as media_ID and mediaID. Is there a way to match for both in one regex?

Comment: Sure!

"asdasdasdasdasd&media_ID=645654654&asdasdasdasd=asdasdasdasdasd".match(/&media_?ID=[0-9]+/)

The _? means that the _ is optional. Also, if you need to match more than one, you should add the "g" for global modificator, such as /REGEX/g, and "i" for in-case sensitive matching.

Comment: When I run that in console it returns "null" for me.

Comment: Also the ID part is the only part that may be lowercase or upppercase. Would this (/&media_‌​?ID=[0-9]+/i) be the proper regex for that? Thanks so much.

Comment: Strange, there's an additional, hidden character after the &media_ and the ? that's why it doesn't work.

Also, yes. It'd be the proper regex! Remember you can always test it in your console.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure it will be followed by an ampersand, you can use regex to find it.

A pattern like `&mediaID=(\d+)&` should suffice.  Then your numbers will be stored in a capture group.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var number = str.match(/&mediaId=(\d+)/)[1];
```